# Avoid ul li in nav and use divs with toggle menu, how can i achieve?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I made my website menu like this:

```
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 active-link">
                        <div class="vertical-align" >
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 nonactive-link">
                        <div class="vertical-align" >
                            <a href="#">MENU<br>ONE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 nonactive-link">
                        <div class="vertical-align" >
                            <a href="#">MENU<br>TWO</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 nonactive-link">
                        <div class="vertical-align" >
                            <a href="#">MENU THREE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 nonactive-link">
                        <div class="vertical-align" >
                            <a href="#">MENU FOUR</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 nonactive-link">
                        <div class="vertical-align" >
                            <a href="#">MENU FIVE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Im not using original nav from bootstrap that is a list (ul li ..)

is there a way i can achive the toggle menu using just divs with col-xs-12 ?

How can i put my code to achieve that just using divs whit col's?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean by toggle menu? can you reference the exact component from the bootstrap 3 docs that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Toggle menu, i mean the small button with 3 lines, that only appears in small devices! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to actually make it a nav menu you need some bootstrap utility classes on the most parent nav element `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` and then you need to add the menu "three lines" icon HTML

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

Then you need to add some more utility classes and ID to the wrapper of the actual nav links `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">` with making sure the id matches the `data-target` in the nav button itself.

The bootstrap doc on this is [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

Also I made a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/amirarafat1/g5munj5b/1/) with your original HTML and modified it, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the example! im using it right now :)

Comment: Glad I could help you.